# Understanding about the numpy.where

Tags: python, numpy

I am reading the `numpy.where(condition[, x, y])` [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), but I can not understand the small example:

```
>>> x = np.arange(9.).reshape(3, 3)
>>> np.where( x > 5 )
Out: (array([2, 2, 2]), array([0, 1, 2]))
```

Can some one explain how the result comes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first array (`array([2, 2, 2])`) is the index of rows and the second (`array([0, 1, 2])`) is the columns of those values that are more than 5.

You can use `zip` to get the exact index of values :

```
>>> zip(*np.where( x > 5 ))
[(2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

Or use `np.dstack` :

```
>>> np.dstack(np.where( x > 5 ))
array([[[2, 0],
        [2, 1],
        [2, 2]]])
```

Comment: What does the * indicate?

Comment: @Raghuram It's the in-place unpacking operand which unpacks an iterable. In this case it will passes the the items and indeices tuples from `np.where` to `zip` function.

Comment: Thank you very much. Learnt something new today! :)

Answer (score 2):

It's printing out the coordinates to your condition

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(9.).reshape(3, 3)
print x
print np.where( x > 5 )
```

where print x prints:

```
[[ 0.  1.  2.]
 [ 3.  4.  5.]
 [ 6.  7.  8.]]
```

and `np.where( x > 5 )` prints the index location of all elements greater than 5

```
(array([2, 2, 2]), array([0, 1, 2]))
```

where 2,0 == 6 and 2,1 == 7 and 2,2 == 8